# Can I join two different research labs as a Ph.D. student?

Tags: phd, advisor, supervision, lab-management

I'm a PhD student and there are two labs that work in very similar fields, but different departments. Both look great, but I'm not sure which will benefit my research more (resources, collaboration, job opportunities, etc.).

Would you recommend I join both labs at first and then decide 1-2 years later? And, if both are really great down the road, is it okay to stick with both at the same time?

Note: I'm in social sciences. One lab in CS department and the other in Arts/Humanities department.

Comment: Does your program allow you to join two different labs? For the PhD program I was in, it was *normal, expected, and supported* for students to *rotate* among 2-4 labs during their first year and then choose one, but not every program supports this trajectory.

Comment: Good question, and I don't know ATM. One thing that I should note is that in social sciences, it isn't expected that every student should even join a lab. Finding a lab, and joining, are up to the initiative of the student. Like no professor has told me that I should find a lab as a first year student yet.

Comment: Eh, I'd suggest you look into that: "joining a lab being up to the students' initiative" and "it isn't expected that every student should even join a lab" don't necessarily go together: the first can be true even if the second is not. Ultimately, you *need need **need*** a research advisor. "Joining a lab" and choosing an advisor are ultimately the same step.

Comment: @BryanKrause: In some of the social sciences (and almost all of the humanities), research isn't organized into labs.  Many students work only with their advisor, and work in a library, an archive, or in the field, without being in a lab.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo OP still needs to choose an advisor to work with. Probably the one in CS considers their group a "lab", even if employees work in libraries, archives, and the field, rather than a proper laboratory. Maybe the one in an arts/humanities department does not consider themselves a lab, but OP's use of "lab" to describe them suggests that they do.

Comment: If your faculty advisor agrees, and your department chair agrees, and if the person or persons in each lab that you would be reporting to all agree, maybe. Do all those people agree?

Comment: @BryanKrause It is true that most social science professors don't even have a lab. They have their graduate students that they advise, but not organized in such way that other departments have their labs (with their own funding, research space, etc.). But yes, they could be the same depending on how you view it. Anyway, that is besides the point. In my case, it's a choice between two "real" labs, not a choice between 2 advisors.

Comment: @puppetsock Would you suggest talking about this to the professors heading the labs? That could be touchy... maybe something that should be avoided? But yes, talking to faculty advisor and department chair is safe.

Comment: It does require a country tag. In many this can be possible only if the two leading the labs already collaborate or start a collaboration, perhaps prompt by your ideas. Formally you might have a single supervisor, or perhaps two.

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "join a lab"? In my department, "joining a lab" is trivial; I have joined a lab and all I do is go to weekly lab meetings. There is no standard for what "joining a lab" means, which makes the answer to this question easy. However, I'm not in CS or SS; so I would like some more clarity from what's expected from you when you "join a lab" in your field(s)/department(s).

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim As I understand it, joining a lab means that you actively participate in research activities with the PI and other graduate students. Of course, that could only mean weekly meetings. But to get the most out of it, I would become the PI's RA, and eventually him becoming my (primary) advisor). In my case, I also get an assigned office along with other members.

Comment: @juansalsa Then your question is "Can I work with two professors for a couple years before deciding who will be my primary advisor?" But your primary advisor has to be in the dept you were admitted to, no?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Not necessarly. I would have to verify this, but my primary advisor may officially be in my dept, but I would be working more closely with prof. outside my dept. This could happen

Comment: @juan I mean, sure, but generally, people don't really want PhD students to only be on the dept on paper, and the other dept doesn't really want one of their professors to take on a student outside of the dept, since that takes their time away from students actually enrolled in that dept.

Comment: You did not write your country (as far as I can see) which is bad.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, these sorts of relationships are encouraged. People like to see collaboration, not only from a scientific perspective, but from a networking and professional development standpoint.

Usually, nothing is needed to *join* a lab, other than a willingness on your part to participate. If you want a mentor-mentee relationship with an advisor who is not in your department (i.e. the department you were admitted to), that is something you will have to negotiate with them. As I mentioned in the comments, students in the advisor's own department are their first priority for mentorship and time.

You say in the comments:

> I would have to verify this, but my primary advisor may officially be in my dept, but I would be working more closely with prof. outside my dept.

While possible, I just want to warn you that this is probably not the most likely outcome, although it's possible standards in your fields may be more permissible.

You should also keep in mind obligations to your home department. If you are funded on an RAship (or an internal fellowship, likely), then you are expected to devote 20 hours/week to your funder's lab, not leaving you much time to work for the other advisor. Of course, the other advisor may fund you, but again, it is probably hard to devote a line of funding to a student outside of the department. Your primary advisor may make your duties including working for the other professor, but I can't tell you how likely that is.

If you are on an external fellowship, your time is much more flexible.

**Tl;dr:** Having a primary mentor outside of your home department is probably not likely, but a good mentor would help you arrange something to the best of their ability, as long as you are a good communicator with all three parties.